# Error while migrating from rails 3.2.13 to rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to migrate my existing project from  **rails 3.2.13**  to  **rails 4.2.0** . I am resolving issues step by step. But now I am kind of stuck.

In some model I am defining some associations with conditions.

In rails 3.x.x the syntax was

```
has_one :avatar, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id", :conditions=>"user_type = 'User'"
```

But in rails 4.x.x, from some rails tutorials I get to know that the syntax changed like any of the below format.

```
has_one :avatar, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", -> { where("user_type= 'Applicant'") }
```

or

```
has_one :avatar, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id", -> { where user_type: 'Applicant' }
```

I tried both syntax. But while starting the server it is throwing the following error which I am not able to figure out.

```
root_path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load': root_path/app/models/applicant.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)
```

So please help any one. Without resolving this I can't go ahead.

Thanks.

Comment: What's on line 20 of `app/models/applicant.rb`?

Comment: has_one :avatar, class_name: "Assets", foreign_key: "applicant_id", -> { where("type= 'Applicant'") }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order of the declaration to this:

```
has_one :avatar, -> { where("type = 'Applicant'") }, class_name: "Assets", foreign_key: "applicant_id"
```

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one) for `has_one`, we can see the signature is:

> has_one(name, scope = nil, options = {})

That is, your scope comes before your options.